# Input text element with different display text and value in Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a use case in which there is a input text element in which if a person enters 2345 it should be displayed as 2,345 but in back end it should store the number as 2345. How could we achieve this in Angular 2?

Comment: You can use `toLocaleString()` - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: just do such as the value corresponds to what's displayed (if input text is `2,345`, value would be the same), but filter the `,` and eventuelly convert to number when you actually use it, much simpler

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/6306281

Comment: I also used toLocaleString()  to add commas to the number but the issue was when I was trying to get the value of input element it is giving the value with commas. And a lot of code has been written so it will require a lot of changes to remove the commas from all occurrences. So I thought if there is a way we could display the number with commas only on UI without changing much. I also tried custom directives but same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using angular inbuilt filter pipe for numbers will do it https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

```
{{1234 | number}}
```

Output

```
1,234
```

Comment: OP is asking for Angular 2 so you should describe the usage of pipes as described [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

Comment: I think we can't use pipes on input elements

Answer (score 0):

You can make a directive, that use @HotListener blur and focus

```
@Directive({ selector: "[app-number]" })
export class NumberFormat implements OnInit {

  private el: HTMLInputElement;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.value = this.transform(this.el.value);
  }

  @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
  onFocus(value) {
    this.el.value = this.parse(value); // opossite of transform
  }

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
  onBlur(value) {
    this.el.value = this.transform(value);
  }

  //value --> value formatted
  transform(value:any) 
  {
     ...return your value formated...
  }
  //value formated--> value 
  parse(valueFormated:any){
      ..return the real value....
  }
```

Comment: I also made one custom directive which was formatting the input on key down event and formatting the input as the user types but the problem began when I tried to get the value of the input after user tabs out. Fetched value contains commas which is causing other functionality to break as they are expecting only a number.

Answer (score -1):

Hope [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/mO257aew7YKXaIzSwS6G?p=preview) would be useful:

Index.html:

```
<body ng-app="numberFilterExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('numberFilterExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.val = 1234.56789;
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Enter number: <input ng-model='val'></label><br>
  Default formatting: <span id='number-default'>{{val | number}}</span><br>
  No fractions: <span>{{val | number:0}}</span><br>
  Negative number: <span>{{-val | number:4}}</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Protractor.js

```
 it('should format numbers', function() {
   expect(element(by.id('number-default')).getText()).toBe('1,234.568');
   expect(element(by.binding('val | number:0')).getText()).toBe('1,235');
   expect(element(by.binding('-val | number:4')).getText()).toBe('-1,234.5679');
 });

 it('should update', function() {
   element(by.model('val')).clear();
   element(by.model('val')).sendKeys('3374.333');
   expect(element(by.id('number-default')).getText()).toBe('3,374.333');
   expect(element(by.binding('val | number:0')).getText()).toBe('3,374');
   expect(element(by.binding('-val | number:4')).getText()).toBe('-3,374.3330');
});
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your answer - otherwise this should be a comment

Comment: sure, will take care for this